# XMLHttpRequest for sending files is not sending the data to the server

Tags: python, angular

I want to upload files from a angularjs 2 app to my python server application.

the formData look perfect before sending it to the server. Containing name and file data.

On the other end is a Python API waiting to accept the file data. But i don't get the data. Debugger PDB get activated as the send is done by angularjs 2 app but i am missing the file data.

What could i be doing wrong?

upload.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';   
import {Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class UploadService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  uploader(files: any) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const formData = new FormData();
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
       formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
    }
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
              resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response))
          } else {
              reject(xhr.response)
       }
     }
   }
   xhr.open('POST','http://192.168.1.205:5000/zino', true)
   xhr.send(formData)
 }
```

}

python flask API debugger

As you see, the request.values are empty :(

```
  <Request 'http://192.168.1.205:5000/zino' [POST]>
  (Pdb) request.values
  CombinedMultiDict([ImmutableMultiDict([]), ImmutableMultiDict([])])
```

Comment: It is not going cross domain. so that is not the reason, i don't get any error of the cross domain acceptance

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example for RC angular2

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class UploadService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  uploader(files: any) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    const formData = new FormData()
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
      formData.append(files[i].name, files[i])
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
              //resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response))
          } else {
              //reject(xhr.response)
        }
      }
   }
   xhr.open('POST','/server/upload-api', true)
   xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')
   xhr.send(formData)
 }
}
```

On the python side you find the files in

```
(Pdb) req.httprequest.files
ImmutableDict({'IMGP0269.jpg': <FileStorage: u'IMGP0269.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>, 'IMGP0270.jpg': <FileStorage: u'IMGP0270.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>})
```